# Combining the rows with overlapping data ranges in SAS

Tags: sas

Since I am new to SAS I need some help to understand how to combine the overlap date ranges into one row.I want to combine the overlap date ranges when they have matching Id. If the dates don’t overlap then I want to keep them as it is. IF they over lap by Matching Id and drug code Then it should combine into one line. Please look at the same ple data set which I have below and the expected results:

```
            Current Data set:           
            ID  Drug Code   BEG_Date    End_Date
            1   100 1/1/2018    1/1/2019
            1   100 1/1/2018    3/1/2018
            1   100 2/1/2018    04/30/2018
            1   90  4/1/2018    04/30/2018
            1   100 5/1/2018    6/1/2018
            1   98  6/1/2018    8/31/2018
            1   100 9/1/2018    5/4/2019

            Expected results:           
            ID  Drug Code   BEG_Date    End_Date
            1   100 1/1/2018    3/31/2018
            1   90  4/1/2018    04/30/2018
            1   100 5/1/2018    6/1/2018
            1   98  6/2/2018    8/31/2018
            1   100 9/1/2018    5/4/2019

            I wrote some SAS code but I am combining the dates even when there is no overlap. I want to write some code which should work in SAS.           

            PROC SORT DATA=Want OUT=ONE;            
                BY PERSON_ID BEG_DATE DRUG_CODE END_DATE;       
            RUN;            
            data TWO (DROP=PERSON_ID2 DRUG_CODE2 BEG_DATE END_DATE          
                RENAME=(BEG2=BEG_DOS        
                END2=END_DOS));     
                SET ONE;        
                RETAIN BEG2 END2;       
                PERSON_ID2=LAG1(PERSON_ID);     
                DRUG_CODE2=LAG1(DRUG_CODE);     

                IF PERSON_ID2=PERSON_ID AND DRUG_CODE2=DRUG_CODE AND BEG_DATE LE(END2+1) THEN       
                    DO; 
                        BEG2=MIN(BEG_DATE,BEG2);
                        END2=MAX(END_DATE,END2);
                    END;    
                ELSE        
                    DO; 
                        SEG+1;
                        BEG2=BEG_DATE;
                        END2=END_DATE;
                    END;    

                FORMAT BEG2 END2 MMDDYY10.;     
            RUN;            

            DATA THREE(DROP=BEG_DOS END_DOS SEG);           
                RETAIN BEG_DATE END_DATE;       
                SET TWO;        
                BY PERSON_ID SEG;       
                FORMAT BEG_DATE END_DATE MMDDYY10.;     

                IF FIRST.SEG THEN       
                    DO; 
                        BEG_DATE=BEG_DOS;
                    END;    

                IF LAST.SEG THEN        
                    DO; 
                        END_DATE = END_DOS;
                        OUTPUT;
                    END;    
            RUN;
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Where does `End_Date = 3/31/2018` come from in the first row of your expected results? Why are you dropping the first row of your input that shows drug 100 for all of 2018? Why wouldn't that overlap with all the other records for drug 100?

Comment: I want to have the end date changed based on the other drug code-90 which has beg date from 04/01/2019. If there are any overlaps between the drug codes then I want to break it down to have single date range across all the drugs losing the minimum data.

Comment: Looks like when the drug changes you want to truncate the previous drug's end date to be one day before the start of the new drug?  Is that right?  So you don't expect anyone to be talking multiple drugs?  Like asthma drug and blood pressure drug?

Comment: What calendar are you using ? April 31 ? Is this April fools data ?  Please update the question with real sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. Create an obs for each ID DRUG and DATE.  Flag the gaps and summarize by RUN.

```
data have;
   input ID  Drug_Code   (BEG End)(:mmddyy.);
   format BEG End mmddyyd10.;
   cards;
1   100 1/1/2018    3/1/2018
1   100 2/1/2018    04/30/2018
1   90  4/1/2018    04/30/2018
1   90  6/1/2018    8/15/2018
1   100 5/1/2018    6/1/2018
1   98  6/1/2018    8/31/2018
1   100 9/1/2018    5/4/2019
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
/*1   100 1/1/2018    1/1/2019*/

data exv/ view=exv;
   set have;
   do date = beg to end;
      output;
      end;
   drop beg end;
   format date mmddyyd10.;
   run;
proc sort data=exv out=ex nodupkey;
   by id drug_code date;
   run;
data breaksV / view=BreaksV;
   set ex;
   by id drug_code;
   dif = dif(date);
   if first.drug_code then do;  dif=1; run=1; end;
   if dif ne 1 then run+1;
   run;
proc summary data=breaksV nway missing;
   class id drug_code run;
   var date;
   output out=want(drop=_type_) min=Begin max=End;
   run;
Proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I still see the overlaps in the output for different drug codes. Also there is no overlap for the Drug codes 100 from 02-01-2018 to 04-30-2018, and next row has from 05-01-2018 to 06-01-2018. Actually speaking both doesn't have the overlaps. The beg date wont fall under the end date.

Comment: Apparently I don't understand the problem and I don't understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the extent range composed of overlapping segment ranges requires a good understanding of the range conditions (cases).

Consider the scenarios when sorted by start date (within any larger grouping set, G, such as `id` and `drug`)

- Let `[` and `]` be endpoints of a range
- `#` be date values (integers) within
- `Extent` be the combined range that grows
- `Segment` be the range in the current row

**Case 1** - Growth. Within G Segment *start* **before** Extent *end*

Segment will **either** *not contribute* to Extent **or** extend it.

```
   [####]       Extent
+    [#]        Segment range DOES NOT contribute
 --------
   [####]       Extent (do not output a row, still growing)
```

or

```
   [####]       Extent
+    [#####]    Segment range DOES contribute
 --------
   [#######]    Extent (do not output a row, still growing)
```

**Case 2** - Terminus. 3 possibilities:

1. Within G Segment *start* **after** Extent *end*,
2. Next G reached (different `id`/`drug` combination),
3. End of data reached.

#2 and #3 can be tested by checking the appropriate `last.` flag.

```
   [####]       Extent
+        ..[#]  Segment beyond Extent (gap is 2)
 --------
   [####]       output Extent
           [#]  reset Extent to Segment
```

You can adjust your rules for Segment being **adjacent** (gap=0) or **close enough** (gap < threshold) to mean an Extent is either expanded, or, output and reset to Segment.

Note: The situation is a little more (not shown) complicated for the real world cases of:

- missing *start* means the Segment has an unknown start date (presume it to be epoch (0=01JAN1960, or some date that pre-dates all dates in the data or study)
- missing *end* means the Segment is active today (end date is date when processing data)

Sample code:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(42);
  do id = 1 to 10;
    do _n_ = 1 to 50;
      drug = ceil(rand('UNIFORM', 10));
      beg_date = intnx ('MONTH', '01JAN2008'D, rand('UNIFORM',20));
      end_date = intnx ('DAY', beg_date, rand('UNIFORM',75));
      OUTPUT;

    end;
  end;
  format beg_date end_date yymmdd10.;
run;

proc sort data=have out=segments;
  by id drug beg_date end_date;
run;

data want;
  set segments;
  by id drug beg_date end_date;  * will error if incoming data is NOT sorted;

  retain ext_beg ext_end;
  retain gap_allowed 0; * set to 1 for contiguously adjacent segment ;

  if first.drug then do;
    ext_beg = beg_date;
    ext_end = end_date;
    segment_count = 0;
  end;

  if beg_date <= ext_end + gap_allowed then do;
    ext_end = max (ext_end, end_date);
    segment_count + 1;
  end;
  else do;
    extent_id + 1;
    OUTPUT;
    ext_beg = beg_date;
    ext_end = end_date;
    segment_count = 1;
  end;

  if last.drug then do;
    extent_id + 1;
    OUTPUT;
    * reset occurs implicitly;
    * it will happen at first. logic when control returns to top of step;
  end;

  format ext_: yymmdd10.;
  keep id drug ext_beg ext_end segment_count extent_id;
run;
```